# Magento2 How to get parent product(configurable) by child product using REST API

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, api, rest-api

How to get parent product(Configurable) by child product(Simple) sku or id using REST API?

I can't find in this list:
https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_22.html

plz help me..

Comment: can't touch server any files, just using REST API

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 does not have any APi.

So you have to create a new API point for this requirement.

Create below files:

> ```
>  1. app/code/Devbera/Configurable/etc/webapi.xml
>
>  2. app/code/Devbera/Configurable/etc/di.xml
>
>  3. app/code/Devbera/Configurable/Api/ConfigurableManagementInterface.php
>
>  4. app/code/Devbera/Configurable/Api/ConfigurableManagementInterface.php
> ```

### Define api point at webapi.xml.

**And code is below:**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" ?>
> <routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
>   <route method="GET" url="/V1/devbera-configurable/:childId">
>       <service class="Devbera\Configurable\Api\ConfigurableManagementInterface"
>                method="getParentIdsByChild"/>
>       <resources>
>           <resource ref="anonymous"/>
>       </resources>
>   </route>
> </routes>
> ```

### And WebApi interface ConfigurableManagementInterface.php

And code is :

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" ?>
> <routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
>   <route method="GET" url="/V1/devbera-configurable/:childId">
>       <service class="Devbera\Configurable\Api\ConfigurableManagementInterface"
>                method="getParentIdsByChild"/>
>       <resources>
>           <resource ref="anonymous"/>
>       </resources>
>   </route>
> </routes>
> ```

### `ConfigurableManagement.php` for getting parent product

> ```
> <?php
> /**
>  * A Magento 2 module named Devbera/Configurable
>  * Copyright (C) 2019 amitbera.com
>  *
>  * This file included in Devbera/Configurable is licensed under OSL 3.0
>  *
>  * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
>  * Please see LICENSE.txt for the full text of the OSL 3.0 license
>  */
>
> namespace Devbera\Configurable\Model;
>
> use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
>
> /**
>  * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
>  */
> class ConfigurableManagement implements \Devbera\Configurable\Api\ConfigurableManagementInterface
> {
>     /**
>      * @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable
>      */
>     private $configurable;
>     /**
>      * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
>      */
>     private $productRepository;
>     /**
>      * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory
>      */
>     private $productFactory;
>
>     public function __construct(
>        Configurable $configurable,
>        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
>        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory
>     ) {
>         $this->configurable = $configurable;
>         $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
>         $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * {@inheritdoc}
>      */
>     public function getParentIdsByChild($childId)
>     {
>         $parentIds = $this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
>
>         $parentList = [];
>         if (!empty($parentIds)) {
>             foreach ($parentIds as $parentId) {
>                 $parentList[] = $this->productRepository->getById($parentId);
>             }
>         }
>
>         return $parentList;
>     }
> }
> ```

### And di.xml for rewrite interface with Model management class

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" ?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
>   <preference for="Devbera\Configurable\Api\ConfigurableManagementInterface"
>               type="Devbera\Configurable\Model\ConfigurableManagement"/>
> </config>
> ```

Full module avaliable at [Github](https://github.com/devamitbera/mse-get-parent-product-Configurable-by-child-product)

Comment: Wow, seems like an oversight for the API. I can think of plenty of use cases for want to grab the parent product based on the child. Is this still true today?